# Getting a ProtocolViolationException with Google Chrome and HTTPListener

Tags: c#, .net, browser, httplistener

I have developed an admin tool where I use a simple HTTPListener to return HTML pages. Everything works well with **IE** and **FF** but I'm getting a *ProtocolViolationException* when using **Google Chrome**.

This is the simplified code (raised from listener.BeginGetContext) that produces the error:

```cs
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><body>response sent!</body></html>");
context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); //<-- crashes here
context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
context.Response.Close();
```

The exception

*Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified.*

is thrown from line

context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

What Chrome does or doesn't do to produce this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I know it's a bit too late, but I've just encountered this problem (not with Chrome) and found this question.
This seemingly bullet-proof code fails when you try to write something to OutputStream in response to a HEAD request. ContentLength64 is then set to 0, and for some reason there is no exception thrown when you try to change it, new value is just silently ignored.

Comment: For the record, you must at least call close on the response stream when receiving a HEAD request, else you'll stay stuck.