# System.Net.ProtocolViolationException:Bytes to be written to the stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified

Tags: c#, outputstream, httplistener

I write web server code base on HttpListener, but often occur exception like it

> "System.Net.ProtocolViolationException:Bytes to be written to the
>   stream exceed the Content-Length bytes size specified".

sample code:

```
context.Response.Output = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xxx");
if (context.Response.Output != null && context.Response.Output.Length > 0)
{
    context.Response.ContentLength64 = context.Response.Output.Length;
    using (var stream = context.Response.OutputStream)
    {
        stream.Write(context.Response.Output, 0, context.Response.Output.Length);
    }
}
```

This exception is not every time request occur.
Who can tell me how fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have the same issue as the question below.  You need to check if the HttpMethod is a HEAD request; in that case you can't write bytes to the OutputStream and attempting to do so will throw the exception you are getting.

[ProtocolViolationException with Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227534/getting-a-protocolviolationexception-with-google-chrome-and-httplistener)

Comment: but i only used GET,POST,PUT,DELETE in httpMethod.

Comment: A client can still send you a head request. Do you catch that and log and error and bail out?  If not then you need to check if you are getting a head request in this case.

Comment: I send HEAD request with Fiddler, server throw ProtocolViolationException. browser will automatically send a HEAD request?

Comment: Yes, a browser can send you a HEAD request, or, depending on where you are deploying and running this, something else is sending your server a HEAD request.  Did you add a log statement for when HttpMethod is HEAD?  Is that getting hit?  It seems like it is.